# How to retrieve specific data from html using XPath?

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing, xpath

Hey guys I am having a hard time trying to get the stock price from a site using XPath.

the html is this:

```
<span class=" price">
<meta content="14.400" itemprop="price">
14.400
<span itemprop="priceCurrency"> BRL</span>
</span>
```

The path I used to retrieve the 14.400 value (all of them getting me null), were:

```
@"//span[@class=' price']";
@"/span[@class=' price']";
@"span[@class=' price']";
@"//meta[@itemprop='price'"];
@"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span/meta";
@"//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span/meta";
```

After trying a lot more the closest I could get to what I need was using this xPath:

```
@"//span[@class=' price']/meta";
```

to get this log:

```
2014-02-07 13:50:39.616 manejoderisco[2838:60b] {
nodeAttributeArray =     (
            {
        attributeName = itemprop;
        nodeContent = price;
    },
            {
        attributeName = content;
        nodeContent = "14.280";
    }
);
nodeName = meta;
}
```

But still returning me null value...

Comment: Your HTML isn't well structured... (no closing `meta` tag). Is this the code you really are dealing with? It probably doesn't help.

Comment: Yes I know that there's no closing meta tag, but the original code is like that, without closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to create the correct xPath which is this one:

```
@"//span/meta/@content
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you are trying to parse isn't well formed, since there is no closing tag for `meta`.
However, if you are indeed able to catch the meta tag, you may want to select the content:

```
//span[@class=' price']/meta/@content
```

Or, if you need the first text field,

```
//span[@class=' price']//text()[1]
```

might work as well.

Don't forget that when you do `//span/meta` you are selecting the `meta` **node**, so `<meta content="14.400" itemprop="price">14.400` (ending wherever, depending on what is using your xpath, since the HTML is malformed). If you want the content, you need to select either `@content` attribute or the text field with `text()`.